# How to read an Internal ConfigurationSection from Web.Config in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, .net, configuration, appfabric, configurationsection

I am trying to read a Microsoft defined ConfigurationSection:

> Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientSection

but the type is internal so I cannot access it in the conventional way.

i.e.

```
var dataCacheClientSection = (DataCacheClientSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("dataCacheClient");
```

I know I can use reflection but do I have any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the configuration file as XmlDocument and read whatever you want there using XPath.

Something like:

```
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + ".config");
XmlNode setting = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("configuration/...");
```

Use the correct XPath in SelectSingleNode

Comment: Thanks. Was afraid that it might come down to that.